# map for hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, higher-order-functions

Is there a hash equivalent for `map`?

```
my %new_hash = hash_map { new_key($a) => new_val($b) } %hash;
```

I know that I could loop through the keys.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[List::Pairwise](http://search.cpan.org/~tdrugeon/List-Pairwise-0.29/lib/List/Pairwise.pod) claims to implement exactly that syntax -- see `mapp`, `grepp`. I haven't used it though.

Also, you can do it as

```
%new_hash = map { new_key($_) => new_value($hash{$_}) } keys %hash;
```

which I admit looks clumsier if `%hash` is really a `$deeply->{buried}->{hash}`. I prefer using `$temp = ...; map {...} keys %$temp` in such cases.

Comment: You are assigning to a hash. Suppose i want to create a hash map reference (`{ something => 42 }`) that is passed to a function instead. It seems the result is an array then. If I assign the result to a scalar, I'm getting a HASH ref, but when I print it (without assigning), I get an ARRAY. Maybe explain in some more detail.

Answer (score 11):

I really can’t see what you are trying to do here. What does “a hash equivalent for `map`” even mean? You can use `map` on a hash just fine.  If you want the keys, just use `keys`; for example"

```
@msglist = map { "value of $_ is $hash{$_}" } keys %hash
```

although usually

```
say "value of $_ is $hash{$_}"  keys %hash;
```

is just fine.

If you want both, then use the whole hash.

For assignment, what’s wrong with `%new_hash = %old_hash`?

Do you have deep-copy issues?  Then use `Storable::dclone`.

Do you want both key and value available in the closure at the same time? Then make a bunch of pairs with the first map:

```
@pairlist = map { [ $_ => $hash{$_} ] } keys %hash
```

I need to see an example of what you would want to do with this, but so far I can see zero cause for using some big old module instead of basic Perl.

Comment: I was looking for a more elegant alternative to using `keys`. `List::Pairwise` and `List::Gen`, as suggested, provide such. Never had any assignment trouble, so that's probably a misunderstanding. As to when it's worth it using a module to simplify the program, I suppose it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Tim: List::Gen seems somewhat interesting, but I can’t for the life of me think of why anyone would use List::Pairwise, since it hides what’s happening in a way that `map { "got $_ => $h{$_}" } keys %h` make perfectly obvious. That said, I do find myself constructing *ordered* pair list often enough, by which I mean ordered lists of ordered pairs.

Comment: Where is that syntax `say String keys Hash;` documented, and where doesn't it produce a syntax error near "keys"?

Answer (score 6):

You can use map like this:

```
my $i = 0;
my %new_hash = map { $i ^= 1 ? new_key($_) : new_val($_) } %hash;
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was just a special case. I'd like `new_key` and `new_val` to be functions of both the key and value. (This answers the question I asked, though.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mapn` from my module [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) to do this:

```
use List::Gen 'mapn';

my %new_hash = mapn {new_key($_[0]) => new_value($_[1])} 2 => %old_hash;
```

`mapn` is like map, except it it takes an additional argument, the number of elements to walk the list by.  Inside the block, the `@_` array is set to the current slice.

Comment: Thanks, that's even more general.

Answer (score 3):

$ perl -d /dev/null

```
  DB<2> %p = ( a=>'b', c=> 'd');                                                
  DB<5> p Dumper \%p                                                            
$VAR1 = {
          'c' => 'd',
          'a' => 'b'
        };
```

To e.g. reverse the key and the value:

```
  DB<6> %q = map { ($p{$_}, $_ ) } keys %p                                      
  DB<7> p Dumper \%q                                                            
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => 'a',
          'd' => 'c'
        };
```

Comment: As seen in the question and other answers, I know that I could loop through the keys. I was looking to see if there's another solution. (And it was List::Pairwise.)

Answer (score 0):

As of perl 5.20, core utility [`List::Util::pairmap`](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util#pairmap) does exactly that:

```perl
use List::Util qw(pairmap);

my %new_hash = pairmap { new_key($a) => new_val($b) } %hash;
```

It's not necessarily optimal (as it involves unrolling the hash to a list and back) but I believe this is the shortest way in vanilla perl.